# Convert FASM Binary to Decimal

Tags: fasm

Ok, if anyone has heard of FASM and is not on Mac, I need your help.

So, I need to compile FASM on Mac, but I need to download a patch from the forums, and for that I have to register. But for registration, they have an extreme captcha. It gives me a FASM-specific binary number and tells me to convert it to a decimal. But the problem is, I ***can't*** because I need the patch to build FASM. So, if you have FASM, please convert this code: `7AB84H`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing FASM specific to the hexadecimal number __7AB84h__that you gave.

Use this to calculate the decimal value:

```
7 ->  7 * 65536 = 458752
A -> 10 *  4096 =  40960
B -> 11 *   256 =   2816
8 ->  8 *    16 =    128
4 ->  4 *     1 =      4
                  ------
                  502660
```